# How does Redux useSelector affect on react component rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rerender

I don't understand how does my component Word will rerender. I have a redux state keeping my {history: {letters}} state. So the question is: If {**letters**} are passed into useEffect deps array, will my component Word rerender if {**words**} property is changed?

`

```
function Word() {
  const { history: {letters, words} } = useAppSelector(state => state)

  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [letters])

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

`

I expect my component rerender only if letters are changed.

Comment: Why it should rerender if `words` is changed even if you didnt put it into dep array?

Comment: That the main idea of my question

Comment: Are you checking component re-render or the useEffect code block?

Comment: I'm checking component re-render

Comment: Just tested it, so it turned out that the component will eventually re-render even if the value taken from store is not used in the component. But this situation shouldn't take place anyways because eslint or typescript won't let you keep the unused variable.

Comment: In `useAppSelector`, you are returning the complete state. So when any value in state is updated, it will render the component. If your component expect to rerender when letters changes, then only get the letters from useAppSelector `const letters = useAppSelector((state) => state.history.letters);`

Answer (score 1):

You are maintaining a state using Redux. So, the component re-renders if any state used in the component itself is changed. In your case, your `Word` component will re-render if `letters` or `words` or both got changed. That's how it works.

BTW, your `useEffect` should only be triggered upon any change in `letters` only since you have included only `letters` in its dependency array.

If you want to optimize the performance, you can memorize things using `useMemo` and `useCallback` wherever necessary. Pass the dependencies correctly to recalculate them only upon required state changes.

Answer (score 0):

UseSelector will already rerender if the selected part of the state has change. you dont have to add `[letters]` on useEffect

UseSelector is subscribed to the state and if detects any change, it calls `checkForUpdates`

```
 subscription.onStateChange = checkForUpdates
```

and `checkForUpdates` checks if the reference of the state changed, if it did. it calls `forceRender` function so your component renders.

[github useSelector](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/607f1ba30417b631a4df18665dfede416c7208cf/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L72)

`useEffect` is used to dispatch actions to populate the state before the component first renders so useSelector will have access to newly populated the state